# Changing a query on Postgres to use only the Standard SQL Clauses

Tags: sql, postgresql, ansi-sql

I did a query on Postgres and I used the FILTER clause which is available in Postgres 9.4 or greater, but I was told that I could only use standard SQL Clauses.

My query is about counting how many animals have been slaughtered, the amount of slaughtered animals is going to be shown for each enterprise and the animal type:

```
Enterprise(id or name) || cow || sheep || chicken
MacDonals              ||  5  ||  5  ||    1     
Burguer King           ||  7  ||  4  ||    2     
KFC                    ||  1  ||  0  ||    10
```

So I made this native query on POSTGRES 9.4:

```
SELECT e.name
,COALESCE (COUNT(a.id) FILTER (WHERE a.type='cow'))
,COALESCE (COUNT(a.id) FILTER (WHERE a.type='sheep'))
,COALESCE (COUNT(a.id) FILTER (WHERE a.type='chicken'))
FROM enterprise e
INNER JOIN animal_enterprise ae
ON ( ae.enterprise_id = e.id)
INNER JOIN animal a
ON ( ae.animal_id=a.id )
GROUP BY e.id
```

So, I've tried doing subqueries for each type of animal but it is not as good as it should.

Comment: That is already standard SQL

Comment: I thought the same, but the Filter clause is a newer feature in postgres 9.4 or greater, and its equivalent in mysql could not exist or perform in a the same way. Then, the Case clause is more suitable to write queries in a standardize way.

Comment: The filter clause ***is*** part of the SQL standard. And MySQL is hardly  a benchmark when it comes to SQL features or the SQL standard. If you want a statement that runs on Postgres **and** MySQL then you should not request a "standard SQL only" statement.

Comment: Thank you, you did make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly how `filter` works, this can be translated by using a `case` expression inside the `count` function:

```
SELECT e.name
  ,COUNT(case when a.type='cow' then 'X' end) as cow
  ,COUNT(case when a.type='sheep' then 'X' end) as sheep
  ,COUNT(case when a.type='chicken' then 'X' end) as chicken
FROM enterprise e
INNER JOIN animal_enterprise ae
  ON ae.enterprise_id = e.id
INNER JOIN animal a
  ON ae.animal_id = a.id
GROUP BY e.id, e.name
```

I ignored a few anomalies in your query, like the use of `p.id`?? when there is no alias `p` defined anywhere, or the use of `coalesce` without a second parameter.